# Integration of weak derivative of hat function for FEM.

Tags: numerical-methods, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

Just curious, lets say I want to solve

$u''=f$

$u(0)=0 \space\space u(1)=0$

In the weak form the equation looks like

$<u',\phi ' > = <f,\phi>$

Now my question, if I test my test functions $\phi_i$ to be hat functions. The weak derivatives will not be defined at grid points. When I do these inner products numerically, since there is a jump in the derivative of grid points, how am I suppose to use simpsons rule, quadrature, etc, when the function isn't defined at grid points.

Comment: I don't understand what you're tyring to do. $\phi$ are supposed to be $\mathcal{C}^\infty$. And I think your equation should be : $<u',\phi ' > = -<f,\phi>$

Comment: Hi nicomezi, the equation is ok, the integration by parts takes care of the negative sign. I've figured out my issues, will post answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is I was using simpsons rule for the integration, which is troublesome if the function isn't well defined at the gridpoints like in this case. Using midpoint or gaussian quadature, which does not rely on the end points of the integral, does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this very informal.

Assume the domain of your problem is $I=[0,1]$ and let's assume you use 2 elements, $I_1=[0,1/2],\,I_2 =[1/2,1]$.

**NOTE:** Each element has 2 local vertices, so you will have 2 local basis functions on each element. 
However (think about this) the **local** nodes of the element $I_1$ are given by the **global** indices $1$ and $2$. The local nodes of $I_2$ have global indices $2$ and $3$. Say the basis function corresponding to global vertex 1 is $\varphi_1$, for vertex 2 it's $\varphi_2$, and for vertex 3 it' s $\varphi_3$.

If your problem is brought into operator form - as you did above, it can be abstractly written as
$$Au=F$$
where $u$ is the vector of unknowns you're computing, $F$ is the load vector and $A$ is your system-matrix.

Let's consider the matrix $A$:
In your case, you define its entries to be
$$A_{i,j} = -\langle \varphi_i',\varphi_j'\rangle_{L^2}$$
You then compute each of the entries by splitting the integral appearing on the RHS into the elements, so e.g.
$$A_{1,2} = \sum_{i=1,2} -\int_{I_i} \varphi_1'\varphi_2'\,dx$$
Note that the indices $1,2$ are **GLOBAL** indices, and the basis functions restricted to some element are defined (in your case) to be piecewise polynomials of order 1. Thus you just use the representation on the corresponding element.

**Explicitly:** $\varphi_2$ is the only basis function 'living' on both elements. Say it has the form
$$\varphi_2(x) = \begin{cases}f_1(x),\,x\in I_1\\f_2(x),\,x\in I_2\end{cases}.$$
Then for the above integral you use $f_1$ when integrating over $I_1$ and $f_2$ when integrating over $I_2$.

For $F$ it' the same...

**Let me make clear, that in your example the basis functions, since they are the hat functions, are indeed continuous! The approach I stated is however always applicable.**